# What is the best practice to persist items inside a reorderablelist after change of order

Tags: flutter

[image]

I have a reorderable list where i read the further information of each row on tap from a json file. Each row displays the corresponding json files name. I read these from a local folder in users device. The list shown here enables the user to reorder the items. The problem is I want to ensure persistent reodering by which I mean my app should remember the ordering user made next time the app is launched. I cannot think of anyway to go with this. Do I store a local json file keeping all the file names and the corresponding row index? What would be a best practice for this. This list is though to have row amount of 50 to 200 so I need a scalable solution.

Comment: Have you thought about using the shared preferences (or even a database to store all the items after extracting them from json - saves you the extraction the next time as well)?

Comment: the problem is it is not recommended to keep a lot of information in shared preferences, if my list had 200 items it would cause problems with shared preferences. I believe it throws an exception after some threshold and overall shared preferences is usually recommended for settings alike things, like maybe game difficulty

Comment: Database then? Seems a good idea for other reasons as well. As you want to keep the positions it feels like you actually want to keep the items as well, so having them in a database might be your best solution here.

Comment: Seems reasonable as I want fast insertion and fast reads, I think a database would be good